# Android Studio - Listview with multiple columns and different appearance

Tags: android, listview, background, textview

I'm working with a database with two separate tables from SQLite, my CRUD operations are working fine. I'm then displaying two listviews on the same activity, one above the other, this is also working fine. In summary I followed the following steps:

- I created two object classes, each with its own getters/setters. Each object class has been attributed a table from SQLite. Each table from SQLite has 5 columns and multiple rows
- I created two custom adapters, one for each listview
- I created the xml layout for the activity showing the two listviews; also one row layout with textviews for each listview.

Each listview has 6 columns. The first column is the position of the item/row in the listview and the other 5 columns contain the values from the respective tables in SQLite.

If I run the application at this point, everything is perfect, I can see both listviews one above the other, showing the data from the SQLite tables.

Now I want to compare the values from listview2 with the values from listview1. If, for example, the textview from position1/row1, column2 in listview2 is equal to any of the items from listview1, that particular textview should have a different background.

I managed to compare the values and set the background. The issue is that if the condition is met and I set the background on the textview from listview2, position1/row1, column2, the background will change automatically on the entire column2 from listview2.

So how do I change the background on a single textview programmatically based on a condition without affecting any other textviews from the other rows/columns in the same listview?

Many thanks.

**EDIT - ADDED ListView2 adapter code**

As mentioned, I can change the background for a particular textview if a condition is met, however this will happen for the whole column even if the conditions are not met on the other rows in the listview.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ObjectSaved objectSaved = getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView ID_fav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_favorit);
    TextView N1_fav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.n1_fav);
    TextView N2_fav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.n2_fav);
    TextView N3_fav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.n3_fav);
    TextView N4_fav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.n4_fav);
    TextView N5_fav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.n5_fav);
    TextView N6_fav = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.n6_fav);

    // Setting the text to display
    ID_fav.setText(position + 1 + ".");
    N1_fav.setText(ObjectSaved.N1_fav);
    N2_fav.setText(ObjectSaved.N2_fav);
    N3_fav.setText(ObjectSaved.N3_fav);
    N4_fav.setText(ObjectSaved.N4_fav);
    N5_fav.setText(ObjectSaved.N5_fav);
    N6_fav.setText(ObjectSaved.N6_fav);

    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getContext());
    databaseAccess.open();
    ArrayList<ObjectDrawingLine> Result = databaseAccess.getSingle(id);
    All_Fav = databaseAccess.getAllFav();
    databaseAccess.close();

    // We're initialising our custom adapter with all our data from the database
    AdapterListView1 adapterExt = new AdapterListView1(getContext(), Result);

    for (position = 0; position < All_Fav.size(); position++) {
        String checkN1Fav = getItem(position).getN1_fav();
        String checkN2Fav = getItem(position).getN2_fav();
        String checkN3Fav = getItem(position).getN3_fav();
        String checkN4Fav = getItem(position).getN4_fav();
        String checkN5Fav = getItem(position).getN5_fav();
        String checkN6Fav = getItem(position).getN6_fav();

        String checkN1Ext =  adapterExt.getItem(0).getN1Ext();
        String checkN2Ext =  adapterExt.getItem(0).getN2Ext();
        String checkN3Ext =  adapterExt.getItem(0).getN3Ext();
        String checkN4Ext =  adapterExt.getItem(0).getN4Ext();
        String checkN5Ext =  adapterExt.getItem(0).getN5Ext();
        String checkN6Ext =  adapterExt.getItem(0).getN6Ext();

        if (checkN1Ext.equals(checkN1Fav) ||
                checkN2Ext.equals(checkN1Fav) ||
                checkN3Ext.equals(checkN1Fav) ||
                checkN4Ext.equals(checkN1Fav) ||
                checkN5Ext.equals(checkN1Fav) ||
                checkN6Ext.equals(checkN1Fav)) {
            N1_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_circle);
        }
        if (checkN1Ext.equals(checkN2Fav) ||
                checkN2Ext.equals(checkN2Fav) ||
                checkN3Ext.equals(checkN2Fav) ||
                checkN4Ext.equals(checkN2Fav) ||
                checkN5Ext.equals(checkN2Fav) ||
                checkN6Ext.equals(checkN2Fav)) {
            N2_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_circle);
        }
        if (checkN1Ext.equals(checkN3Fav) ||
                checkN2Ext.equals(checkN3Fav) ||
                checkN3Ext.equals(checkN3Fav) ||
                checkN4Ext.equals(checkN3Fav) ||
                checkN5Ext.equals(checkN3Fav) ||
                checkN6Ext.equals(checkN3Fav)) {
            N3_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_circle);
        }
        if (checkN1Ext.equals(checkN4Fav) ||
                checkN2Ext.equals(checkN4Fav) ||
                checkN3Ext.equals(checkN4Fav) ||
                checkN4Ext.equals(checkN4Fav) ||
                checkN5Ext.equals(checkN4Fav) ||
                checkN6Ext.equals(checkN4Fav)) {
            N4_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_circle);
        }
        if (checkN1Ext.equals(checkN5Fav) ||
                checkN2Ext.equals(checkN5Fav) ||
                checkN3Ext.equals(checkN5Fav) ||
                checkN4Ext.equals(checkN5Fav) ||
                checkN5Ext.equals(checkN5Fav) ||
                checkN6Ext.equals(checkN5Fav)) {
            N5_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_circle);
        }
        if (checkN1Ext.equals(checkN6Fav) ||
                checkN2Ext.equals(checkN6Fav) ||
                checkN3Ext.equals(checkN6Fav) ||
                checkN4Ext.equals(checkN6Fav) ||
                checkN5Ext.equals(checkN6Fav) ||
                checkN6Ext.equals(checkN6Fav)) {
            N6_fav.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_circle);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its kinda hard without code, but maybe you have to set default background for textview which arent suppose to have different background.

Comment: So you're saying that I should set a default background in the row layout for textview which aren't supposed to have different background. I don't think this would work because I don't know which should have default and which shouldn't. It depends on the data from SQLite which are changing based on the CRUD operations (adding more data, deleting etc). I can provide code but which part would be required to come with a solution?

Comment: I assume you are changing the background in getView method. When creating the view try something like `if (backgroundChange) something else default ` ... and maybe try to post getview method in original question

Comment: I've added the getview method in the original question, many thanks again

Comment: Hmm check the if conditions please... `checkN2Ext.equals(checkN1Fav)` is there multiple times.

Comment: And in third "if" you have N1_fav.setBackgroundResource which should be N3_fav I suppose

Comment: Yes, you are right, I corrected in the original question, although this still doesn't solve the main issue.

Comment: Try for every "if" make an else branch where you setBackgroundResource to "default" one.

Comment: Just tried but it doesn't change anything. From my point of view, the reason why this doesn't work is this: If we take N1_fav for example, first we attach convertView.findViewById(R.id.n1_fav) from the row layout. Second, assuming that the if condition is met, we change the background to N1_fav so this will happen on every row, even if the condition is not met on the other ones. I don't know how to change this behavior though.

Comment: yeah you are right I didnt notice that you iterate trough position, you shouldnt because the getView method returns view for only one row and then it goes to another. So in your case the last item in the array sets the background. It should be enough to remove the for cycle

Comment: And one more thing. You are creating some AdapterListView1, are you sure its necessary? I think you only want Result.getItem(X).... And when we are at it, if its not really necessary, you shouldnt access database from getView at all, because of performance. You should get all items in activity/fragment and in constructor for adapter use the array with all the items as one of the parameter.